# how to get a windows batch file to update itself safely

Tags: batch-file

e.g. I want to run a windows batch file, say upgrade.bat, which copies a bunch of files from a source directory to the directory that the batch file is in. Problem is, one of the files copied might be a newer version of upgrade.bat, so that the batch file will overwrite itself while its still running.

This seems to result in some unpredictable behavior of batch file execution, so I want to avoid copying over a batch file which is still running. Ideally, I want the existing version of upgrade.bat to run until it is finished, and next time run the new version. Are there any (simple) ways to achieve this ?

Comment: Rename the file before executing it?

Comment: @Chad - do you mean rename upgrade.bat from inside upgrade.bat itself ? Would that be safe and result in predictable behavior ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the copy as the last operation using the start command to launch it from another terminal. Check this example, specially the last lines.

```
@echo off
set CUR_FILE=batman.bat
set FOUND_EQUAL="FALSE"
set FROM_DIR=c:\temp\galeria\

SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /R %FROM_DIR% %%F IN (*) DO (
  SET "p=%%F"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET ABC=!p:%FROM_DIR%=!

  IF NOT !ABC! == !CUR_FILE! ( 
echo copying %%F
    copy "%%F" . 
   )    
ENDLOCAL  
) 

echo trying to copy file with the same name [last operation] 
start copy "%FROM_DIR%%CUR_FILE%" .
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to do that, the following requirements must be satisfied:

- The overwrite of the Batch file for the newer version of itself must be the last command of the Batch file, so the next command after the `copy` must be an `exit /B` or `exit`.
- Previous commands must be loaded in memory before they are executed. This is easily done by enclosing them in parentheses.

That is:

```
@echo off
rem Do program business here...
echo Anything

rem Parse/load following commands before execute they:
(
rem Copy many files, probably a newer version of myself
xcopy /Y *.*
rem You may execute other commands here...
echo Files copied!
rem Terminate *this version* of the running Batch file
exit /B
)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
IF /i NOT "%~dp0"=="%temp%\" (
 COPY /y "%~dpnx0" "%temp%\%~nx0" >nul
 "%temp%\%~nx0"

)
ECHO Now we run the rest of the original UPGRADE.BAT
```

This sequence of lines at the start of `upgrade.bat` should work.

See whether we're running from a copy in `%temp%`. If not, then copy this file to temp & run it from there.

Hence the batch actually runs from `%temp%` and the original version may be overwritten.

Comment: @Peter_Wright:this looks interesting but why wouldn't the "ECHO Now we run the rest of the original UPGRADE.BAT" ... run after the file was copied and run?

Comment: @steve When you run the original, the directory is NOT the temp directory, so a copy is made into temp, and executed, which transfers execution to the COPY. When the COPY runs, %0 is in the temp directory, so it runs the original code from the copy (ie, from the ECHO on.) Now - if your ORIGINAL is in `%temp%` you're likely to get an error since yu'd be trying to copy a file over itself.

Comment: @Peter_Wright: Very simple and elegant once I figured out that weird syntax. I modified it slightly to also delete it from temp after running it there and then exiting.

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
cmd /c copy "C:\somepath\upgrade.bat" "%0" & %0
```

This would start a new cmd process and replace the current batch file with "C:\somepath\upgrade.bat" and restart the batch file

Answer (score 2):

Would it be an option to tag each new version of the batch file with a version suffix and use a second batch file as a launcher?

For example say you are payload batch file is **upgrade.bat**, subsequent versions will be named as upgrade_001.bat, upgrade_002.bat, upgrade_003.bat .. or upgrade_201305122134 (suffix being yyyymmddHHMM), the new batch file **launcher.bat** would look for the latest batch upgrade file by looking for the one with the highest suffix and execute it

Comment: not a bad idea, I think you're onto something with the launcher batch file idea. Although upgrade.bat is in source control, so not really keen to rename it each time it is changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
if NOT "%1"=="RUN" (
copy "%~0" temp_update.cmd
temp_update.cmd RUN
)
```

Just put this at the top of your cmd file
any name can be used for the temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Make the batch file copy itself to `updateNow.bat` and then run `updateNow.bat`:
So contents of `update.bat` is:

```
if %0 == update (
  copy update.bat updateNow.bat
  updateNow.bat
) else (
  copy newUpdate.bat update.bat
)
```